# Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (11:16)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

- I am new to js
- I am trying to move All of this logic  in a helper function instead of in the render method
- I am facing a syntax error.
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.

> ./src/components/first-time-tab/player-setup.jsx
>
> Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/workspace/fasg-sports-dashboard/src/components/first-time-tab/player-setup.jsx: Unexpected token (11:16)

```
   9 |     renderAccountTabContent() {
  10 |             return (
> 11 |                 let sportsStartDate = this.props.playerInfo.sportsStartDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your error, it shows you trying to `return` a variable assignment, not code.  Put this line outside the return.

Try this ...

```
renderAccountTabContent() {
        let sportsStartDate = this.props.playerInfo.sportsStartDate;
        let renderData;

        let now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let past1Days = moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let past2Days = moment().subtract(2, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let past3Days = moment().subtract(3, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        if(sportsStartDate && sportsStartDate === now) {
            renderData = 'We’re setting up your player and verifying the funds you’ve deposited. Don’t worry — it might take a couple of days for your player to reflect your balance.';
        } else if(sportsStartDate && sportsStartDate === past1Days) {
            renderData = "We’re setting up your player and verifying the funds you’ve deposited. Don’t worry — it might take a couple of days for your player to reflect your balance.";
        } else if(sportsStartDate && sportsStartDate === past2Days) {
            renderData = "We’re making some progress. See what’s happening today.";
        } else if(sportsStartDate && sportsStartDate === past3Days) {
            renderData = "We’ve put your money to work in your investment player.See what’s happening today.";
        } else {
            renderData = "Your new portfolio is a work in progress. See what’s happening today.";
        }

        return (
            renderData
        );
}
```

Comment: Awesome ... glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: can you help me me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732658/npm-install-classnames-not-working-in-my-li-tag