# npm install classnames not working in my li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

- I am new to React JS.
- I am trying to combine my classes using npm package classnames. https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames
- but it's not working:

> `classname` is not executing first-time-active ... am I using it correctly? When I use normally the class is working.

- can you guys tell me what's the problem? It's in this line:

  ```
  <li role='presentation' key={index} className={`${liClassName} ${className}`}>
  ```
- providing code below:

  ```
  import CombineClassName from 'classnames';





          let managedProductActivationDate = this.props.accountInfo.managedProductActivationDate;

          if(managedProductActivationDate === undefined || managedProductActivationDate === '') {
              className = 'first-time-active';
          } else if (managedProductActivationDate !== '') {
              className = `ft-prev-day`;
          }
  ```

Comment: What issue or error is occurring?

Comment: @rfornal hey this class name is not executing first-time-active ....am I using it correctly...when I use normal way this class is executing

Comment: Did you intend to return two `<li>`'s and one of them is not closed (this one you referenced as the problem.

Comment: BYW - really like the answer that **Kelly J Andrews** posted.  Better than I could have done quickly.

Comment: @rfornal thanks. It _should_ work, unless there is some other issue I'm not aware of.

Comment: You'll get there ... I'll keep an eye out for more issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity and legibility - import the `classnames` modules as `classnames`.  This will make it easier to read everything later, and you won't be second guessing what goes where.

The main issue you have in the code above is this line:

```
var CombineClassName = `${liClassName} ${className}`
```

You were

1. not actually calling the module
2. overwriting the module with the string literal.

The `classnames` [documentation](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) is really solid, and should help you figure things out as well.

Essentially, you want to pass into the `classnames` method any thing that will evaluate to `true`.  Anything that evaluates to `false` will be excluded.  With this in mind you can actually include your logic right inside the method, and it will evaluate and return the correct class names for you.

I rewrote the `labels` method a little to help you out.

```
function labels(child, index) {
    let isActive = this.state.selected === index;
    let content = isActive ? this.props.children[this.state.selected] : null;    
    let managedProductActivationDate = this.props.accountInfo.managedProductActivationDate;

    const classes = classnames(
      child.props.liClass,
      {
        'first-time-active': (managedProductActivationDate === undefined || managedProductActivationDate === ''),
        'ft-prev-day': managedProductActivationDate !== ''
      }
    )

    return (
        <li role='presentation' key={index} className={classes}>
          <a 
            href='#' 
            className={`sports-tab-header`}
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, index)}>
              <h2>{child.props.label}</h2>
              <p className="sports-subtitle">{child.props.subtitle}</p>
          </a>
          {content}
        </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...but I am getting the below error now  ERROR in ./src/components/first-time-tab/first-time-tab-content.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/workspace/fasg-dia-dashboard/src/components/first-time-tab/first-time-tab-content.js: Unexpected token (36:19)

  34 |
  35 |             const classes = classnames({
> 36 |               child.props.liClass,

Comment: I see what I did. I added extra curly braces that were not needed.

Comment: I am trying to learn js...can you tell me why we should not add extra {}

Comment: You could if the first option was also set to true, but the way I did it you only need the object the for the second argument passed in.

Comment: Plus, the value is a variable there, and it needs to be passed in separate. The documentation for claasnames gives a full over view of all the variations you might need.

Comment: yeah it worked...can you help me with one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776856/remove-css-class-when-we-switch-tab-from-li-tag

Comment: Mind checking this one as answered?

Comment: yeah sorry i fprgot...can you help me with other one